# In Redis, how do I get the expiration date of a key?

Tags: database, redis

What's the command I use to see how many seconds are remaining?

Answer (score 80):

```
TTL key
```

See the documentation of the [TTL command](http://redis.io/commands/ttl).

There is also a [`PTTL` command](http://redis.io/commands/pttl) since Redis 2.6 that returns the amount of time in milliseconds instead of seconds.